# Questions about the proof of equivalence of two definitions of normal extensions in Lang's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

In Chapter 5.3 of Lang's Algebra, there is a theorem claims that these three conditions of normal extensions are equivalent:
[image]

My question is about how we can deduce NOR 1 assuming NOR 2. It seemed to me at first that this fact could be proved using Corollary 3.2 of the same chapter:
[image]

I guess there is something wrong in my proof because Lang himself did not give a proof in this way. But I can't figured out what exactly is wrong in my proof. The following is my proof:

The algebraic closure $k^a$ of $k$ is also an algebraic closure $K^a$ of $K$, since $k^a$ is naturally an algebraic closed field and we can deduce that $k^a$ is algebraic over $K$ by the fact that $k[X]$ is a subring of $K[X]$. Then we use Corollary 3.2 of the same chapter.

In Corollary 3.2 we let $E=K$. Thus every embedding of $K$ into $k^a$ (i.e. $K^a$) over $k$ induces an automorphism of $K$ as we wish.

Could anyone show me where the error is, or (highly impossible as I believe) there is nothing wrong about my proof? Thanks in advance!

edit:
The following is Lang's proof of NOR 1 assuming NOR 2, where one can see he avoided to use Corollary 3.2.
[image: Lang's proof of NOR 1 assuming NOR 2]

Comment: No, I don't see anything wrong with your reasoning.

Comment: @CaptainLama   I raised doubt about my reasoning not only because it felt not correct to me, but also because the author proved Theorem 3.3 in a different way, without using the corollary just above this theorem as I did. Could there be any possibility that Lang just wanted to show the reader another way of proving, or is there some vulnerability in my reasoning which Lang's proof avoided? I've uploaded a screenshot of Lang's proof for reference. Anyway, thank you very much！

Comment: But the reasoning he uses is exactly the reasoning that one would use to prove Corollary 3.2, so I don't see the difference. Sometimes when it only takes a couple lines it can be better to repeat a reasoning rather than refer to an earlier proof. Or maybe he even wrote Cor 3.2 later in the writing process and did not update this proof. Or he just forgot about it. I can't know. In any case, it seems to me you are overthinking this, and your reasoning is fine.

Comment: @CaptainLama  Thank you very much. It seems I did overthink about this. And it's also right of your point that he's repeating an earlier proof.